# Automated Visual Studio Source Changes on Build (Update DBML etc.)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, post-build

Every time I rebuild by DBML, I have to adjust settings for auto generated value etc. for individual fields.

Is there a built-in tool which I could use to automate my changes in the DBML when I build? I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found anything built-in.  I just use a T4 template that reads my database on builds and updates the DBML file with new columns and datatype changes - nothing else.  That way, once a table is place on the DBML file, you never need to worry about losing your customizations.  It's a pain, but a simple workable solution.  Though I'd love to know if someone has a better (and free-as-in-$$$) idea.